# RavenDB Put Trigger

Tags: ravendb

I have searched high and low on RavenDB Put Trigger. However, I couldn't find a source where I can get the task completed. Here is my little dll code that I have stored inside Ravendb's Plugins folder - I am using build 960. My question is, how do I go from here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Raven.Database.Plugins;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Raven.Json.Linq;
using Raven.Abstractions.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Raven.Tryouts
{
public class MyPutTrigger : AbstractPutTrigger
{
public override void OnPut(string key, Json.Linq.RavenJObject document,       Json.Linq.RavenJObject metadata, Abstractions.Data.TransactionInformation transactionInformation)
    {
        base.OnPut(key, document, metadata, transactionInformation);
        Debug.WriteLine("OnPut: " + key);
    }
    public override void AfterPut(string key, Json.Linq.RavenJObject document, Json.Linq.RavenJObject metadata, Guid etag, Abstractions.Data.TransactionInformation transactionInformation)
    {
        base.AfterPut(key, document, metadata, etag, transactionInformation);
        Debug.WriteLine("AfterPut:" + key);
    }
    public override void AfterCommit(string key, Json.Linq.RavenJObject document, Json.Linq.RavenJObject metadata, Guid etag)
    {
        base.AfterCommit(key, document, metadata, etag);
        Debug.WriteLine("AfterCommit:" + key);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Compile this code.
- Take the resulting dll and place it in the Plugins directory (next to the .config file). If necessary, create the Plugins directory.
- Restart Raven

Comment: hi and many thanks. i did exactly the same as the above. But nothing on client output window when i PUT a new document. The Plugins must be inside the Server folder?

Comment: Yes, the default for the plugins folder is in the server folder.  You can put it elsewhere and set the new location in the ravendb config file.  See misc setting in the documentation http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Debug.WriteLine does not write to the RavenDB debug log. Start Sysinternals DebugView on the server where Raven is running to view the system debug output - there you'll see the diagnostic output from the example trigger.